# Override java dependency in react native library

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I need to use a react native library called [@ihealth/ihealthlibrary-react-native](https://github.com/iHealthDeviceLabs/iHealth-React-Native-SDK)
I added it to my project, but on build I get an error `Could not find no.nordicsemi.android:dfu:1.6.1`

This package version seems to be no longer available, so I would like to override the version in my react native app.

I added the following in `MyProject/android/app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  implementation("com.ihealth.ihealthlibrary:iHealthLibrary:1.5.1") {
    exclude group:'no.nordicsemi.android:dfu:1.6.1'
  }       
  implementation("no.nordicsemi.android:dfu:1.8.0")
}
```

I then get this error: `Could not find com.ihealth.ihealthlibrary:iHealthLibrary:1.5.1.`

Basically I can't figure out what's the correct package name and version to put in my config.
Where can I find this ?

Answer (score 1):

This lib is really outdated. Go into the libraries `build.gradle` file and replace this `implementation 'no.nordicsemi.android:dfu:1.6.1'`

with: `implementation 'no.nordicsemi.android:dfu:1.8.0'`

then create a patch: `yarn patch-package  @ihealth/ihealthlibrary-react-native`